# Optimization of code (HTML/CSS) for a simple case of border on a div

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner on HTML5/CSS3, and even if I've found a way to solve the problem I'm faced, i'm pretty convinced I'm not solving it the right way.

Some explaination : I'm trying to reproducte the exact same thing (see below), in this case the problem was on the "border"/underline under each category, the little thin grey line, not the blue one.

[image]

Firstly I tried to put a border-bottom on all these  with a padding, but the problem was that each grey line didn't have the same width.

Then I realized that the original grey border were maybe the border of the "block" of each sentences, not the sentence itself. So I created a class="border" that I duplicated for each sentence in my list, like this :

[image]

Which gives me the exact result I want. And I just wrote in my CSS (result on 2nd picture under):

```
.border{
    border-bottom: 1px #b2b2b2 solid;
}
```

[image]

But I don't find esthetic the way I wrote it on my HTML code.

Is there anyway to rewrote this pls ?

Thank's a lot people.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the code, let alone _links_ to the pictures of the code, post the actual code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: LIs are not valid children of DIV and DIVs are not valid children of UL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, here's the answer

HTML:

```
    <nav id="liensarticle3">
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Sed neque nisi consequat</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Dapibus sed mattis blandit</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Quis accumsan lorem</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Suspendisse varius ipsum</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Eget et amet consequat</a></li>
             </ul>
```

CSS :

```
    #liensarticle3 > ul > li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px #b2b2b2 solid;
}
```

Comment: Yes, obviosly it's better. And if you don't want the border under the last item in the list, simply omit that `border1` class.

Comment: @Neo78 top! it is good! +1up

Answer (score 1):

Just give a width to li's so get the equal border-bottom

Comment: Yeah that would work too you ' re right I guess. I'll try it later, its maybe even more optimized than what I've done !